# Set a Zend Decoration for radio element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I need to set a decoration for to print:

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" value="foo">
<label for="option1"></label>
<label>Option 1</label>
```

using Zend_Form_Element_Radio.

I've tried:

```
$pass = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('options');
    $pass->setLabel('Bloquear:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addMultiOptions(array(
                'option1' => '<label for="options-1"></label><label>Option 1</label>',
                'option2' => '<label for="options-2"></label><label>Option 2</label>'));
    return $pass;
```

but it prints the labels like a not HTML. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'for to print'? Why would you want an empty label tag?

Comment: It means to show, to display... For customization of radio button using CSS. ^^

Answer (score 0):

you have to define custom decorator as below example to manage with `<ul>` and `<li>`

it would be easy to apply css on bases of ul and li. take look on that

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'Bloquear', array(
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('AddTheLi' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'li')),
        array(array('AddTheUl' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'ul')),
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),

    // specifying the "div" tag to wrap your <label> elements is not strictly 

    // necessary, but it produces valid XHTML if your form elements are wrapped

    //  in block-level tags like "<li>" (see next comment)
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'div')),

    // uncomment the following if all of your form elements are wrapped in "<li>"
    //array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'li')),
),
'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
'label' => 'Bloquear',
'separator' => '</li><li>',
'attribs' => array(
    'options' => array(
        'foo' => 'Option 1', 
        'bar' => 'Option 2', 
        'baz' => 'Option 3'
    ),
),
```

));

please let me know if i can assist you more.

Comment: sorry @liyakat, that does not answer my question.

Comment: It shows something like: 
<label>
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" value="foo">
'test'
</label>
In others words, the input is inside the label. the already tested dozens of things like that.